Is it possible to process dataset names from another file/syin?
Essentially I’d like to store a list of dataset names in another file/sysin, then process over that list using each dataset name as a sortin.
My first thought was to create a proc that would take in a single dataset name. This requires adding a step for each file that I want to process.

You can generate a JCL using DFSORT with all the file names and submit that JCL via Internal reader. However note that you can only have 255 steps per job, so if your filelist is more than that you need to insert another job card for every 255 dataset names.  A sample of input files, the desired output files along with SYSIN control cards would help.

Thanks for the suggestion! I was considering writing a COBOL program to generate a JCL in a similar way. I’ll look into using a sort card to generate the JCL too
